# Javascript Destructuring: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

im able to do this

`[a, b] = await function1(a, b)`

but when i do this

`[a, b] = await function1(a, b)
 [a, b] = await function2(a, b)`

i get this error message

```
SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression
[a, b] = await function1(a, b)
         ^
[a, b] = await function2(a, b)
```

i have found a work-around but would like to know if theres a way to make my example work.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it with a semicolon at the end of the call to `function1()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add semicolons in. It thinks the second set of `[a, b]` is part of the same expression, and more specifically that it's an array index. Ie, it sees this much:

```
[a, b] = await function1(a, b)[a, b] =
```

... and then thinks "woah, i can't assign anything to `await function1(a, b)[a, b]`"

So instead do:

```
[a, b] = await function1(a, b); // <-- added semicolon, fixing the issue
[a, b] = await function2(a, b); // <-- added semicolon for consistency
```